# Specific mysql record listing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
        <section class="latest-news-index">
    <table style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;margin-bottom: 20px; "class="table table-hover ">
            <tbody><tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;border-top: none;font-size: 2.1em;font-weight: bold;" colspan="99" class="date-header"><?php echo date('m.d.y');?></td></tr>
            <?php

            $sayfa = $news->pager($SAYFA,15,'haber','h_id',"WHERE onay='1' AND time<='".time()."'");
            $sql = $db->sql(
    "SELECT haber.h_id, 
            haber.k_id, 
            haber.baslik, 
            haber.baslik_renk, 
            haber.resim, 
            haber.k_icerik, 
            haber.link, 
            haber.time, 
            kategori.baslik as kategori 
    FROM haber 
    LEFT JOIN kategori ON haber.k_id=kategori.k_id
    WHERE kategori.onay='1' 
      AND haber.onay='1' 
      AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(haber.time)) = DATE(SYSDATE())
    ORDER BY haber.time DESC 
    "
);
            if($db->num_rows($sql)>0):
                $i = 1;
                while($data = $db->f_array($sql)):
        $id     = $news->dataview($data['h_id']); // news id
        $baslik = $news->dataview($data['baslik']); // news title
        $baslik_renk= ($news->dataview($data['baslik_renk']) ? ' style="color:'.$news->dataview($data['baslik_renk']).';"' : ''); // title color 
        $resim      = $news->dataview($data['resim']); // news image
        $kIcerik    = $news->dataview($data['k_icerik']); // News desc
        $time   = $news->dataview($data['time']); // News date
        $kategori = $news->dataview($data['kategori']); // category
        $haberlink  = $news->dataview($data['link']); // seo_link
        $link = ($haberlink == '' ? $news->url('haber',$id,$baslik) : $haberlink); // generation link
        $photo = $news->dataview($data['fg_id']); // getting photo gallery id for news content
        $video = $news->dataview($data['vd_id']); // getting video id for news content 
        ?>
                <tr class="item">
            <?php if($sistem['iceriktarih']): ?>
        <td class="time"><?=$news->saat($time)?></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="category"><?=$kategori?> </td>
        <td class="title"><b><a href="<?=$link?>"><?=$baslik?><span class="title-icons"></span></a></b></td>
    </tr>

        <?php
                endwhile;
            endif;
        ?>            
    </tbody></table>

</section>
```

Hello friends,
My system has: video, photo, "breaking news"

This is how my system should work:

> If news has video it should have video Icon.
>
> If news has photo gallery it should have photo icon.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing is you code is too ugly. keep clean it and post only where you stuck.do not post your whole code.

Comment: use if statements , where are you icons ?

Comment: Video icon: <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
Photo icon: <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>

Comment: @ReshoMarcos Im here to help you but i have trouble understanding your problem.so its so simple you should use `if (condition){ }else{ }` but what is the condition?

Comment: The condition is video news or photo news or just a news.

if photo news then News title should be with photo icon. 
else video news then news title should be with video icon.

Comment: Ok man i know it. Where is the "news type"? so how you understand which news has video or which news has images? You know your code is not good. You have used bad grammar in your code like instead of using word news you have used haber. Like you don't have comments in your code so i don't understand you code.

Comment: @MishelParkour Yes, you are right. I've updated my code.. can you have a look at my code again? please.

Comment: @ReshoMarcos, more questions I'm afraid. $photo and $video are your indicator that there is one (and what it is), but where do you want to display it? It would be inside one of your existing <td>, or in an extra one (or two) that make a space for that?

Comment: @MishelParkour and boisvert ;  I've posted a screenshot about what i am trying to make [link](https://imgur.com/a/ZDIUD)

Comment: @ReshoMarcos that screenshot helped alot. But still i dont know about your data structure and other sutff, so i cant help you finding the flag. You may even need to change your database to be able to have that flag. But after you had flag you can use the answer i gave you

Answer (score 0):

> @ReshoMarcos that screenshot helped alot. But still i dont know about
>   your data structure and other sutff, so i cant help you finding the
>   flag. You may even need to change your database to be able to have
>   that flag. But after you had flag you can use the answer i gave you

OK with that screen shot you sent its more clear but still i dont know where you store the flag (the data you are gonna decide if the news has video or if it has image)

So as far as i see here is where you want to show the icons

```
<td class="title"><b>
    <a href="<?=$link?>"><?=$baslik?><span class="title-icons">^^^^^^^here^^^^^</span></a>
</b></td>
```

So based on your flag. (the variable that holds data that can help you realize if new has image or video). So you may have the flag already stored in your database (like a filed in a table) or you may have to create the flag base on different conditions and checking the news' type or if video src filed in data base is empty or such things. So lets say you have your flag and it is name `$newType` or `$newsHasVideo`. So this is how your code should look like.

inside while loop after you set the variables:

```
<?php
$newsHasVideo= true; // or false i told you about the flag
if($newsHasVideo){
    $icon = '<span class="icon vid-icon"></span>'; 
    //$icon should be filled with real icon data based on your
    // needs like glyph-icons or font-awesome
}else{
    $icon = '<span class="icon img-icon"></span>';
}
?>
<tr class="item">
<?php if($sistem['iceriktarih']): ?>
    <td class="time"><?=$news->saat($time)?></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="category"><?=$kategori?> </td>
    <td class="title"><b><a href="<?=$link?>"><?=$baslik?><span class="title-icons"><?php echo $icon; ?></span></a></b></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for your helping .. Here is my db structure
[https://pastebin.com/C9PsrGLS](https://pastebin.com/C9PsrGLS)

Comment: @ReshoMarcos. Dude i cant understand it. You need to practice documenting. They are just some short names. Which are not even in english. And you know I can help you analyze and design your databse. But that is not like helping you that is like working for you. Cause it will take much time of me. And I should check your whole database also read and know about your site design. But the help I can give you is just some tips a programmer can give to another programmer. you need a field in your news table. If you hold all type of news in 1 table (picture news and video news) then you need a column

Comment: @ReshoMarcos In your news table. Like news type. So it can be varchar 1. and if the news has picture the field newsType will be 'A' if the news has video the newsType filed will be 'B' and so on. Now in your select query you need to select newsType field too, like the other fields. So you check value of newsType if its A then show picture icon if its B show video icon.

Comment: @ReshoMarcos if you think you still need more help, I can check your database structure. Also other things like your codes and such and help you will all. But this would be like hiring me. Anyway If you were interested I can give you my skype and you will see if you can do it by yourself or you need to hire someone.